# Error TS2339 TS property does not exist. I am doing some homework and ran into this problem. Can anyone answer why this error is occurring?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to complete a homework assignment and ran into this issue.

I have tried declaring http and other solutions providing in visual studio but only end up with more errors.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
    selector: "quiz-list",
    templateUrl: './quiz-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./quiz-list.component.css']
})

export class QuizListComponent {

    title: string;
    selectedQuiz: Quiz;
    quizzes: Quiz[];

    constructor(
        http: HttpClientModule,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string
    ) {
        this.title = "Latest Quizzes";
        var url = baseUrl + "api/quiz/Latest/";

        this.http.get<Quiz[]>(url).subscribe(result => {
            this.quizzes = result;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    onSelect(quiz: Quiz) {
        this.selectedQuiz = quiz;
        console.log("quiz with Id "
            + this.selectedQuiz.Id
            + " has been selected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the errors as well

Comment: At first sight, it seems that `Quiz` interface / class isn't imported